# HashLocationStrategy has no effect in Angular2 RC1

Tags: angular

I am trying to solve the problem where refreshing an Angular2 page results in a 404 error. When I try to implement HashLocationStrategy, it doesn't seem to make any difference to the URLs which are generated.

My main.ts file is:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { provide } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the hashbang approach, solved using server config. Added .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On  
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using the deprecated router for the time being. The current router was never finished and is being replaced with a new, new router.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

`<base href="#">`

inside `<head></head>` section in your `index.html`.

Comment: I think it should be `<base href="/">`. What is `#` for?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer # should serve as an anchor, so there is no "real" redirect